# change boot order gub ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot-loader

I have installed ubuntu server 18.04 on a dedicated server. The problem is i would like to have btrfs for the whole disk ( 1to ), but the web manager don't propose me the option to do so on installation. 
So i have created a new partition, have formated the partition, copied the data from the "/" partition, and changed the fstab. And now i want to boot to the new partition.

I have tried by editing the grub.cfg in /boot/grub, by removing all the entries pointing to the old root partition and making sure only the entry to boot on the new one is left. But it still is booting on the former one.

Can someone explain to me what is the best way to modify the grub cfg to make it boot on my new partition? Or even a minimal grub.cfg ? ( it's a server i don't need option.

Or even maybe do you recommand to use an other bootloader ?

Thanks

Comment: Check old reference people shared many ways to do same things https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order hope some options fit to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's two steps to changing the grub configuration in Ubuntu:

The first is to edit `/etc/default/grub`(instead of /boot/grub/grub.cfg); the second is to run `update-grub` to make the changes. You don't want to edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly in case you make mistakes. `update-grub` will do everything you need to generate the correct kernel arguments and update the grub menu.